Using gcloud storage rsync on Windows
I am trying to sync a Google Cloud Storage bucket with a folder on a Windows server.  When I run this command:
gcloud storage rsync gs://my-bucket/normal C:\my-folder\normal
I get the error below regarding invalid characters.  It eventually completes successfully, but I am wondering if there is a way to suppress the error.  The files do not have invalid characters; it seems to be a gcloud storage rsync artifact.

At gs://my-bucket/normal/*, worker process 8972 thread 11372 listed 2...
WARNING: The following characters are invalid in Windows file and directory names: /:*?"<>|
Renaming 4633fe1dfa7d9f75413c886d8d8f13bd49b374e9.-images_normal_* to 4633fe1dfa7d9f75413c886d8d8f13bd49b374e9.-images_normal_$2Copying gs://my-bucket/normal/1273_1968_RICR.jpg to file://C:\my-folder\normal\1273_1968_RICR.jpg
Copying gs://my-bucket/normal/158_1943_RICR.jpg to file://C:\my-folder\normal\158_1943_RICR.jpg
  Completed files 2/2 | 174.3kiB/174.3kiB

Average throughput: 42.5MiB/s



(1) Try to enter chcp 65001 before issuing the command. (2) Try using gsutil -m rsync instead of gcloud,

Do any of the folders under gs://m-bucket/normal contain characters from the list of characters that error message reports are disallowed by Windows? GCS would let you create a folder with such a name but then trying to rsync down to a Windows machine would fail with this message if a folder contains one of those characters.

No @Mike Schwartz.  the files originate from windows storage so they are all valid. its clearly the worker process renaming the bucket with an asterisk in it:  "Renaming 4633fe1dfa7d9f75413c886d8d8f13bd49b374e9.-images_normal_* to"...the * is the invalid char.  google bug imo

The warning message when you run the command gcloud storage rsync is a warning about invalid characters in Windows files and directories names not an error indicating that the files themselves have invalid characters.
From a discussion, there was a concern similar to what you were encountering and was directed to this documentation for more details.
To suppress the warning, you can redirect the standard error output to /dev/null using the 2>/dev/null command. You can try this command
gcloud storage rsync gs://my-bucket/normal C:\my-folder\normal 2>/dev/null

Suppressing the error message  that might seem like an error is primarily a notification to help identify potential compatibility issues.

per the title of the post, this is on Windows.  but I tried the equivalent and still got errors. txs anyway.  the discussion focuses on gsutil, which gcp warns to use gcloud storage instead.
